# How do I update a MySQL table each time a page loads?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to debug some things going on within a particular page on my website.

To do this, i have set up a table in my database called '404'.  I would like to write a few values to this table each time the page loads but i'm not having success.

Currently have the following php code at the top of this page:

```
  <?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/incl_func/env_constants.php"; ?>
    <?php
    //check 404 visits
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $refer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    $query = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO 404 (REF_URL, IP, AGENT, DATE) VALUES ('$refer', '$ip', '$agent', '$date')");    
    ?>
```

I think this issue requires that i do this via ajax but I keep running into walls when trying to get this to work.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Check your php log file on the server for errors.

Comment: Where abouts in your code are you running this? What errors are you getting? What's happening that's different from the expected behaviour?

Comment: it's just not writing to the table each time the page loads.  i'm not getting any errors it's just not doing anything.  i expect to have an entry in the database on each page load

Comment: Interesting, if strange approach. why can't you query your server log files for the error?

Comment: try running it from commandline to look for error message:
php yourfile.php

Comment: No reason you need AJAX as long as you can determine those four values as the page is loading, which it seems you should be able to.

Comment: You wouldn't get any errors even if there were any since you have the `@` sign in front of `mysql_query` which will suppress the error. remove the `@` and then see if you get errors.

Comment: What errors does mysql_error($query); give you?

Comment: thanks everyone for the help.  I was able to solve this by looking at the logs--was a better solution afterall.  Turns out the issue with the 404 had to do with yahoo changing its geo locator service today.  I wasn't aware they were discontinuing it

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for the help.  I was able to solve this by looking at the logs--was a better solution afterall.  Turns out the issue with the 404 had to do with yahoo changing its geo locator service today.  I wasn't aware they were discontinuing it